# Multiple Count with different value each record

Tags: sql, database, count, db2

I have a problem with my query, please help me to solve this problem.

My Query :

```
SELECT D.DEPTNO, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.PROJNO) FROM SCHEMA.PROJECT P, SCHEMA.DEPARTMENT D WHERE P.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO) AS PROJECT, 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E.EMPNO) FROM SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE E, SCHEMA.DEPARTMENT D WHERE E.WORKDEPT = D.DEPTNO) AS EMPLOYEE 
FROM SCHEMA.DEPARTMENT D, SCHEMA.PROJECT P, SCEHMA.EMPLOYEE E GROUP BY D.DEPTNO@
```

AND HERE THE RESULT :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG8Y7.png)

but it should each row has a different result.

I must show total of project and employee each department, so i group that by deptno, but the result shown all total project and employee

Please help me guys :)

Comment: Could you please describe your requirement? What do you expect?

Comment: I must show total of project and employee each department, so i group that by deptno, but the result shown all total project and employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to write this query:

```
SELECT D.DEPTNO, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.PROJNO) 
        FROM SCHEMA.PROJECT P
        WHERE P.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
       ) AS PROJECT, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E.EMPNO)
        FROM SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE E
        WHERE E.WORKDEPT = D.DEPTNO
       ) AS EMPLOYEE 
FROM SCHEMA.DEPARTMENT D;
```

Notes:

- You don't need `JOIN`s in the subquery.  The correlation clause is sufficient.
- You don't need a `GROUP BY` in the outer query.
- You probably don't need the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, but I'm not sure so I'm leaving it. in.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: yeah, i study more with your answer, for the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` when you put in there or no is no problem (i was try that hehe)

hehe Thanks for your answer sir, now my problem is solved :) thank you very much :)

regards~

Answer (score 0):

When you join tables - do not forget the join predicates!
If I got your requirement right - this might be a possible solution:

```
select deptno
      ,count_projects
      ,count_employees
from (
  select deptno
        ,count(projno) as count_projects
   from  project
  group by deptno ) as p
inner join 
  (select workdept 
         ,count(*) as Count_employees
     from employee
    group by workdept) as e
on p.deptno = e.workdept
```

The table DEPARTMENT is not necessary unless you have to retrieve specific data from this table as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir :)